# question about where self.kwargs come from if it is not defined? specifically in the SingleObjectMixin class in the django code base

Tags: django, django-views

I am following a Django tutorial and I am creating a CBV that inherits from (SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView) and I was taking a look at the code base when I reached 
    SingleObjectMixin
 which has a function called get_object. It sets

```
pk=self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
```

Where does kwargs attribute come from here? 
because SingleObjectMixin is only instantiating from one class "ContextMixin" and this does not have that attribute

This is a part of the function:

```py
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
        in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.
        """
        # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
        # like DateDetailView
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # Next, try looking up by primary key.
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
        if pk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), it originates from the [**`setup(..)`** method in the **`View`** class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L83):

> ```
>     def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         """Initialize attributes shared by all view methods."""
>         self.request = request
>         self.args = args
>         self.kwargs = kwargs
> ```

This `setup(..)` method is called by the wrapped `view` method that is constructed in the [**`as_view`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L49):

> ```
>     @classonlymethod
>     def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>         # ...
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             # ...
>             self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
>             # ...
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         view.view_class = cls
>         view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
>
>         # ...
>         return view
> ```

If you add a class-based view to an path definition, you do this with `.as_view(..)`. This function will construct a function that is defined by `def view(..)`. This view will construct a new view instance, and call the `self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)` on that view. Next it will call `self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` that will dispatch the call to the correct method (the `.get(..)`, `.post(..)`, etc. method).

A `Mixin` does not need to have a parent class that defines this, since a `Mixin` is, well, mixed into the *method resolution order*, and most class-based views take [**`View`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#view) as the basic class and then add extra logic to that by mixing in mixins, and overriding certain methods. Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can thus override the `setup(..)` method. For example to "pre-process" the `self.request`, `self.args` and `self.kwargs`.

Before [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), it was set in the `view` function that was constructed:

> ```
>     @classonlymethod
>     def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>         # ...
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
>                 self.head = self.get
>             self.request = request
>             self.args = args
>             self.kwargs = kwargs
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         view.view_class = cls
>         view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
>
>         # ...
>         return view
> ```